# Is it "of " or "out of" ( a number of people, items etc)

Tags: grammar, differences, prepositions, numbers

I've kind of got my wires crossed over which one to use.

There's of course the construction - " of all people/ places etc" (Casablanca springs to mind right away, where the protagonist says something along the lines of " of all the gin joints of all towns [...] he walks into mine ")

And then there's on the other hand this one: 3 out of 10 cases, 5 out of every 6 people etc.

---

I'm still having a hard time putting my finger on the right way to say this though:

Why would they choose us, of the thousands of people who probably send them letters each and every month? / ...... OUT OF the thousands of people who....?

Comment: 'Casablanca' is perhaps to a large degree responsible for the acceptability of  'Of all the ...' in examples like this. Go with 'out of' in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **out of**.

> out of preposition (FROM AMONG)
>
> B1 from among an amount or number:
>
> Nine out of ten people said they liked the product. No one got 20 out
>   of 20 (= all the answers correct) in the test.
>
> More examples
>
> Out of all my friends, she is the most ambitious. He's the only child
>   out of the whole class who's not going on the school trip. I've heard
>   that, out of all the applicants for the job, he was the only graduate.
>   Nine out of ten cats prefer this brand of cat food, apparently. I
>   should be able to find one dress out of all this lot that suits me.
>     --[OOD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of)

Why would they choose us, of the thousands of people who probably send them letters each and every month? / ...... FROM AMONG the thousands of people who....?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I would say:

> Why would they choose us out of the thousands of people who will probably send them letters each and every month?

Comment: Hello, Minh Thao. Please be aware that answers that are really valued on ELU will be supported by authoritative reference. Those lacking it look like (and may well be) just one person's opinions. FWIW, I consider the inclusion of the definite article much better here.